# Where do I get the scanner?

Tags: warframe

In *Warframe*, I keep coming across markers in missions that say "requires scanner" like this one:

[image: An item in Warframe requiring a scanner]

I've not come across any sort of blueprint or mission that would unlock said scanner, so I'm not really sure what I need to do here. I've missed several of these.

What is the scanner, and how do I get it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to buy Codex Scanners from the market, and then you equip them in your gear menu/wheel. Then when you see something like that, you press <kbd>Q</kbd> to bring up the gear wheel, select the scan, and then use it to scan.

Alternately, get yourself a Helios companion (you will still need to buy Codex scanners) and it will autoscan things for you.

After you reach Mastery Rank 3, you can also visit [Cephalon Simaris](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Cephalon_Simaris) on any relay. There you can buy [Synthesis Scanner](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Synthesis_Scanner) charges that work in a similar way to the codex scanner, but are more expensive per charge. After earning enough standing with Cephalon Simaris by scanning things and performing a daily quest, you can purchase a scanner upgrade, the Sol-Battery widget, which provides infinite charges to allow you to scan all the things.

Comment: I just found out that you get Codex Scanners as part of the first questline on Cetus.  Tutorial mission on how to use them, maybe?

Comment: "any relay" isn't quite true. Kronia relay on Saturn requires mastery rank 4, and Orcus relay on Pluto is locked behind mastery rank 8.  Not that's it's relevant here, but...

Comment: and yes, @Frank, the Cetus quest is the tutorial for them.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I assume Ash just said "any relay" because it's different based on which platform it is.  For example, the tier 1 relay is Larunda Relay, Mercury on PC; Vesper Relay, Venus for Xbox One; and Strata Relay, Earth on PS4.